# nested forloops for running sliding window function for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a simple code that will generate the sum of a large window and divide by the sum of the small running window to get the energy ratio.

my code looks like this in MATLAB

```
S           = data1;
[nt,ntraces] = size(S);

!Create sliding windows for First Break Picking:

!define a window length
!for large Window
nl = 300            
!for small running Window
ns = 50 
! tolerance/Fudge Factor
beta = 0.0000



for i_slide = 1:nt-nl
for i_large = i_slide:(i_slide+nl)
    large_window(i_large) = sum(S(i_large).^2)';


    for i_small = i_slide+ns:i_slide+nl
        small_window(i_small) = sum(S(i_small).^2)';
    end

end

ER(i_slide) = small_window/(large_window + beta);
end
```

The problem i am having is that my small running window is not indexing correctly nor is it running the sum along the whole large window length at the maximum slide.

any ideas how i can overcome this problem?

Comment: Why are you using "!" instead of "%" for comments? I am pretty sure that "!" will attempt to run the following string as a command on your native OS shell.

Comment: This code looks wrong. What is your goal? For one large window, what do you want to divide it by? You will get many small windows in one large, so you can not just divide one number by many.

Comment: ignore the exclamation marks. just a mistake on my end.

Comment: as for the objective, i want to sum up energy ratios of small windows within a large window. it is easier to show in the attached pdf link
http://library.seg.org/journals/doc/GPYSA7-ft/vol_75/iss_4/V67_1.html

see eq1,2,3 and figure1 under MCM section pg1

Comment: Large window does not have a set length there. It is essentially a sum of squares of your entire signal, is that correct? The small window has length `nl` and is fixed. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: maybe the way i'm stating it in the code is incorrect. I want to create a fixed large window length, within that large window, I want to sum the signal^2. I also want to create a small fixed window length that is running the length of the large window and summing for the small window length.

ideally, I would end up with an energy ratio along the whole signal.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the problem you're really trying to solve seems to be general 2-D (or 1-D?) convolution.   You can use MATLAB's conv or conv2 function (or filter or imfilter, if you have image processing toolbox) to do this.  If you *need* to write a 2-D convolution function, I wouldn't try and write one that does two convolutions and takes the ratio.  Instead write a simple convolution function: my_conv and run it twice, and take the ratio.  e.g., you're trying to write:

```
output = my_double_conv(data,smallFilt,bigFilt); %this does ratios
```

I don't think that's a good idea in general.  Don't do that.  Do

```
output = my_conv(data,smallFilt) ./ my_conv(data,bigFilt);
```

You *might* see some speed benefits from not having to index everything twice in my_double_conv, but if computational concerns are your issue, you shouldn't be writing your own convolution in the first place; instead you should be using FFT convolutions, or integral-image convolutions (e.g., http://hebb.mit.edu/courses/9.29/2004/readings/c13-1.pdf or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table )

That said, your code has several problems.  Have you tried debugging with the MATLAB debugger?

For example, this is clearly wrong, since i_small is a scalar index:

```
for i_small = i_slide+ns:i_slide+nl
    small_window(i_small) = sum(S(i_small).^2)';
end
```

That sum is not going to "sum" over anything, since i_small will be a scalar...

Do you want:

```
small_window= S(i_slide+ns:i_slide+nl);
small_window_sum = sum(small_window.^2);
```

Also note that for element-wise matrix operations, like:

small_window/(large_window + beta);

Where small_window and large_window are scalars, you want:

small_window./(large_window + beta); %note the "."

Comment: Even if you don't need true generic convolution, and just want the energy in rectangular regions, I'd almost guarantee MATLAB's built in functions will be much faster than any double-for-loop answer you can write.